# Django edit default user group and add profile pictures

Tags: python, django

In django I want to edit the default user group so that I can the following attributes to all users, a description, a position, and a profile picture.  I'm fairly new to django so if this question can be improved please let me know.

Comment: It means you have to add an extra field in the `USER` model ?

Comment: @MKPatel I'm talking about the default one that comes with django, it's not in my models.py so how do I edit it

Comment: Yes, it means Django provides USER model and you want to add extra field on USER model of django, right?

Comment: Am I right or not?

Comment: the out-of-the-box User model will not allow you to add additional information, you will have to extend the model. [This link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) gives you a detailed explanation of how you can go about extending your User model

Comment: Yeah you're right @MKPatel

Comment: Also I saw that @Yellowduck I didn't understand it because of my lack of experience with django really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to extend `AbstractUser` as below and add extra field as per your requirements...

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    phone = models.CharField(name="phone", max_length=10, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(name="photo", upload_to='photos/', null=True, default='user_default.png')
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And suppose this `User` model is in app named `app_1` then you have to set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py` as below...

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "app_1.User"
```